# How to reshape data.frame

Tags: r

I'd like to get a function that sorts data frame in the way that equal numbers or 0 (/optionally NA) are in the same column.

It should look similar to this:

```
1 0 3 4 5
0 2 0 0 5
1 2 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you rollback to your previous update

Comment: KonradX: thanks for deleting your other question, (I believe) that's the right thing to do. As suggested in its comments, though, it would be very useful to (1) un-accept @akrun's answer and explain why you are deselecting it; then (2) edit your question to provide sample unambiguous data, code attempted, and expected output. Asking questions in a way that SO deals with *well* is not always intuitive, and most definitely takes extra effort on your part. You will be rewarded by developing this skill, I'm confident. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to convert to `data.frame` and bind with `map_df`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_df(z, as.data.frame) %>%
    mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
```

Comment: Could you help me as well with repositioning this data frame from "triangular matrix" form to the shape I wanted? I've tried to do it by myself, but I failed :/

Comment: @KonradX  The above gives a rectangular format as you intendeed.  I guess the values you mentioned are the `rnorm` values, right

Comment: @KonradX  I am not fully getting the logic for expected output esp when you showed only 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'

Comment: Can you please edit your post and update as the format is not cleear in the comments

Comment: I want to have in every column only 0 and the same number from vector "numbers".
The attached image shows what I got, not what I wanted

Comment: @KonradX  I saw your image update.  Isnt it the same format from my output

Answer (score 0):

Using just base R you could do this.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(z) {x <- t(apply(z, 1, `length<-`, l));x[is.na(x)] <- 0;x}, z))
#             [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#  [1,]  1.3709584  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [2,] -0.5646982  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [3,]  0.3631284  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [4,]  0.6328626  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [5,]  1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [6,]  1.3709584  0.3631284 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [7,]  1.3709584  0.6328626 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [8,] -0.5646982  0.3631284 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [9,] -0.5646982  0.6328626 0.0000000 0.0000000
# [10,]  0.3631284  0.6328626 0.0000000 0.0000000
# [11,]  1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.3631284 0.0000000
# [12,]  1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.6328626 0.0000000
# [13,]  1.3709584  0.3631284 0.6328626 0.0000000
# [14,] -0.5646982  0.3631284 0.6328626 0.0000000
# [15,]  1.3709584 -0.5646982 0.3631284 0.6328626
```

**Explanation:** Essentially this is an `rbind` problem where the matrices in list `z` have different number of columns. Since the needed number of columns is known by `l` we can take each single row of a matrix as a vector with `apply()` and prolong it to `l` with `length<-`. Because this yields `NA`s we need to convert these to the desired zeroes. `Map` applies that to the whole list. Finally wrapping `do.call(rbind..)` around it binds the listed matrices into a single one.

#### Data

```
z <- list(structure(c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.63286260496104), .Dim = c(4L, 1L)), structure(c(1.37095844714667, 
1.37095844714667, 1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, -0.564698171396089, 
0.363128411337339, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 
0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 0.63286260496104), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L)), structure(c(1.37095844714667, 1.37095844714667, 1.37095844714667, 
-0.564698171396089, -0.564698171396089, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.363128411337339, 0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104, 0.63286260496104, 
0.63286260496104), .Dim = 4:3), structure(c(1.37095844714667, 
-0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 0.63286260496104), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)))

l <- 4L
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little? The code is pretty dense.